# SP "New Experience" option missing from lists only

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are using a new subsite as a pilot for rolling out (or allowing the option) of using the New Experience that MS has come up with; this is working fine for the few starter lists when we created the site.  Fast-forward a few weeks and they need a new reference list, except the new experience list setting isn't available or even displayed on the advanced settings page.  Oddly enough, the new experience seems to be working fine for Site Contents and Document Libraries... its only the Custom Lists that have lost the ability to switch In/Out of the New Experience.

If anyone has any advice on where to go next,  I've tried the following:

- Toggle Off/On the Tenant setting
- JSOM - List.set_ListExperienceOptions (no errors, but doesn't update list)
- Cleared cache and tried on IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox.  All the same behavior.
- Our sites DO have Publishing enabled, which I've seen can interfere... although it was enabled from the beginning.
- I've also tested on a site collection that never had Publishing enabled, cannot do New Experience Lists there either.
- It may be worth noting the setting is also missing for lists that currently use the New Experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial rollout of `new experience` SharePoint lists to `First Release` customers has been released in early August 2016 that by default will be enabled.

So, you should be aware of the Modern UX is available for custom lists, so far, not the OOB list types like Tasks and Announcements.  Further customization options are dependent on the release of the SharePoint Framework by year end.  In the interim, classic mode remains fully supported.

Also you should check that "new experience" is selected in SPO central admin & be part of the "First release program" also check how to  [Set up the release option in the Office 365 admin center to first release](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-Standard-or-First-Release-options-in-Office-365-3b3adfa4-1777-4ff0-b606-fb8732101f47)

For more details check

- [modern-sharepoint-lists](https://blogs.office.com/2016/07/25/modern-sharepoint-lists-are-here-including-integration-with-microsoft-flow-and-powerapps/)
- [Modern SharePoint lists are here – Including integration with Microsoft Flow and PowerApps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Modern-SharePoint-lists-are-here-Including-integration-with/bc-p/3692)

Comment: Thank you, an answer/workaround is at the end of your [techcommunity link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Blog/Modern-SharePoint-lists-are-here-Including-integration-with/bc-p/3692):  adding the query argument 'TryNewExperience=true' pushes me to the new experience AND makes the option appear in the advanced settings page for lists...  which is enough to get my tasks done.